# Azure App Service URL Rewriting fails for HTTPS

Tags: azure, ssl, url, url-rewriting

We recently created a new web site and I performed the following steps to redirect users from the old domain to the new one:

- updated the old domain and its appropriate CNAME's to forward to the new domain
- configured Azure to listen for the old domain + subdomains
- added URL rewrite rules to the web.config (301 permanent redirect to new domain)

Everything works fine when browsing via HTTP; however, when browsing via HTTPS, I get errors such as

- The hostname in the website’s security certificate differs from the
  website.
- This server could not prove that it is [old domain]; its security certificate is from *.azurewebsites.net.

I am guessing this is because my app service only holds the SSL certificate for the new domain name, and not the old one. Is there any way around this? Can URL rewriting or some other option preempt this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the certificates for your new and old domains in the same App Service application.

You need to add both certificates, and then add the SSL binding for each one to the appropriate domain.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution we ended up using.